# js запросы на сайт

Tags: javascript

как нажать к примеру на кнопку на чужом сайте `<span class="left_label inl_bl">кнопка</span>`со своего ресурса или локального компьютера с помощью javascript? не пойму как работать с консолью или снифферами анализировать запросы.

Comment: в принципе - никак.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу работы с консолью. Пишем в консоли:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("left_label")[0].click();
```

или

```
document.getElementsByClassName("inl_bl")[0].click();
```

или

```
document.querySelector(".left_label").click();
```

или

```
document.querySelector(".inl_bl").click();
```

и жмём **Enter**.

Comment: это понятно. не правильно воровс поставил я имел ввиду с локального компа или серевера на другом домене не открываю вкладку в браузере этого домена и не загружая страницу этого домена со всей хтмл структурой

Comment: А как можно представить JS-запросы не загружая хтмл структуру?

Comment: с помощью фреймов если сайт не запрещает . или аякс запросами. есть еще способы?

Comment: Ещё это делают на языке JScript, (это не JavaScript) и ещё с помощью десктопных программ. На пример программа AddNews для публикации новостей на сайтах.